# how to pass a value in javascript and get it on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**JavaScript**

```
function resultfunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    window.location.href = "deleteresult.php?did="+result;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<select id="result">
<?php
   include 'model.php';
   $rs=new database();
   $res=$rs->result();
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $did=$row["id"];
        $dterm=$row["term"];
?>          
<option id="<?php echo $dterm;?>"><?php echo $dterm;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<a href="#" onclick="resultfunction()" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Delete </a>
```

this is my code on the click of delete i want that javascript take id of selected option and take it to next page.... and how to get it on next page .. i want to use it as a php variable on next page ????

Comment: $_SESSION['did'] = $did; and you can use it on all pages. For more info get php session doc's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to have a value on the `option` like:

```
<option id="option1" value='1'>option 1</option>
```

I've made you a `jQuery` demo, see snippet below:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var result = $("#result").val();
  console.log(result);
  //I've commented this line just for demonstrating purpose
  //window.location.href = "deleteresult.php?did=" + result;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="result">
    <option id="option1" value='1'>option 1</option>
    <option id="option2" value='2'>option 2</option>
    <option id="option3" value='3'>option 3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Delete </a>
```

A Javascript alternative would be to use `addEventListener` instead of the deprecated `onclick`:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var select = document.getElementById("result");
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(selectedOption);
     //I've commented this line just for demonstrating purpose
    //window.location.href="deleteresult.php?did=" + selectedOption; 
});
```

```html
<select id="result">
    <option id="option1" value='1'>option 1</option>
    <option id="option2" value='2'>option 2</option>
    <option id="option3" value='3'>option 3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="btn dropdown-toggle" id='btn'>Delete </a>
```

Other options would be to use either Javascript's `localStorage()` or PHP's `$_SESSION`

And on the page you will be redirected you can get the value used as a $_GET parameter using:

```
 echo $_GET['did'];
```

Comment: one more thing i want to ask when i am fetching the term from database there is lot of duplicate values but i want it only single time no matter how much time it is repeated in databse

Comment: @YogeshArya, I don't know why you want to do such thing, that depends on the structure of your database tables but I think you can change your `SELECT` query something like: `SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM table_name;` This way you it should return unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```html
<select id="result">
    <option id="option1">option 1</option>
    <option id="option2">option 2</option>
    <option id="option3">option 3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" onclick=" resultfunction()" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Delete </a> 
<script>
  function resultfunction() { 
    var select = document.getElementById("result"); //<---get the select 
    var result= select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; // <--selectedIndex will let you get the value.
    //window.location.href="deleteresult.php?did=" +result; 
    console.log(result);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: one more thing i want to ask when i am fetching the term from database there is lot of duplicate values but i want it only single time no matter how much time it is repeated in databse

Answer (score 1):

And for use that variable on deleteresult.php page u should have some code like this

```
$get_did = $_GET['did'];
```

Comment: one more thing i want to ask when i am fetching the term from database there is lot of duplicate values but i want it only single time no matter how much time it is repeated in databse